# Voice recognition in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i am trying to implement voice recognition in sencha touch 2 .i.e. on the click of a button a speak dialogue comes up and the voice is processed and the identified voice is texted on the textfield.
I have tried this a lot but did not come up with a proper working answer.
some examples are given for sencha touch 1 but none for sencha touch 2 .
Please help me if any one has one answer to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some code/examples and where it is not working?

Answer (score 2):

The feature you mean is the webkit-speech-input by Google for their browser Chrome

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-speech-input-fields/

It's just supported in the Chrome Browser for Mac/Windows/Android.

You can't use it with the normal Safari iOS / Android Browser (afaik).

For the supported browsers just change the ST1 Plugin to ST2

[Sencha Touch 1 Plugin](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.plugin.touch.form.Speech/blob/master/Ext.plugin.touch.form.Speech.js)